# axios request not working with form data on external api

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multipartform-data

I have a external API request as given below.

[image]

Now I need to write this postman API into an axios API call. But I tried to do many alternative things, but nothing seems to work.

The below code explain the current code I tried to do.

```js
const url = `${this._url}/rest/v1.0/files?project_id=${projectId}`;
const response = await Axios.default.post(
  url,
  {
    file: {
      parent_id: +parentId,
      data: file,
    },
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${updatedToken}`,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Procore-Company-Id': company.id,
    },
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
  }
);
```

Comment: try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Comment: did that as well, but it also seems not working, I need a syntax on how to upload using formdata

Answer (score 1):

using [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append( 'my_file', fs.readFileSync('/foo/bar.jpg') );

// In Node.js environment you need to set boundary in the header field 'Content-Type' by calling method `getHeaders`
const formHeaders = form.getHeaders();

axios.post('http://example.com', form, {
  headers: {
    ...formHeaders,
  },
})
.then(response => response)
.catch(error => error)
```

Comment: but the issue is i am using multer to get the file, and it does not have a file path as of now, just the entire file with the buffer data

Comment: @Jithin append can also be used with a buffer `form.append('my_file_from_buffer', <your multer buffer>, {
      filename: myfile.jpeg,
    })`